# Java Regex for password validation

Tags: java, regex

I have created regex for password validation in a Java app. The regex I created is below for below requirement.

```
^[\\p{Alnum}#.!@$*&_]{5,12}$
```

1. At least 5 chars and max 12 chars
2. Contains at least one digit
3. Contains at least one char
4. may contain chars within a set of special chars (#.!@$*&_)
5. Does not contain space, tab, etc.

I am missing 1 and 2 like if I give "gjsajhgjhagfj" or "29837846876", it should fail. But it's not happening.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Is there a reason you restrict it to 12 chars maximum? This doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: There is a reason which I can't share online

Comment: No worries, the good thing is that there are always people willing to help, do NOT be discouraged... Everyone deserved to be helped as long as he shows that he already did some effort and he failed to achieve what he wants, which you clearly did <3

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookaheads to force conditions 1 & 2:

```
^(?i)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9#.!@$*&_]{5,12}$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oY7bU3/2)

`(?i)` is for insensitive match, the same as `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag for your compile function:

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

You can read more about Lookaheads [HERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)